# Simple Modal use <img> inline with description

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplemodal

I am having issues going through our sites modals and trying to fix what previous developers did.

It seems as though they modified each modal individually, to create billables, and I am having issues correcting the UI.

https://jsfiddle.net/devops713/39b1Lfap/

```
<div style="/* overflow:visible !important; */" id="content" class="gwp-modal-content">
```

The image is supposed to be inline with the description and the continue is supposed to be below the $0.00.

Comment: Try using a placeholder image as we don't have the image you're referencing in your jsfiddle. for example http://placehold.it/350x150 for a 350px by 150px image

Comment: Are you asking for a way to do this with modifying CSS only?

Comment: `.purchase-with-purchase` element is positioned `absolute` and there's no parent for it with `relative` or `absolute` position. So that's bad. Why not try to `float` those two elements ?